# I am trying new commands, like Indexof(), and am having problems

Tags: c#, string

Hey I am fairly new to C#, and I don't understand why I have an error right now. I have written this code to take a string and move every character up three places in the alphabet. Right now, It just returns the same string, but I was expecting it to return an encrypted version of the string.

```
namespace Cipher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          

            string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            Console.WriteLine("Type in something you want to encrypt, using only lowercase letters.");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i == (s.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                string a = s.Substring(i, 1);

                int x = abc.IndexOf(a, 0, (abc.Length - 1));
                x = x + 3;

                if (x >= s.Length)
                {
                    x = x - s.Length;
                }
                string b = s.Substring(x, 1);

                s = s.Replace(a, b);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `==` in for loop to `<=`

Comment: This is a great time to learn to use your debugger.  You can step through your program line by line, and you would be able to see that your loop is only executed once.

Comment: [c# visual studio debug program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx) It can help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Correct your for loop condition. Also your program thr' out of index error. 
Can you elaborate more which encryption algorithm your trying for?

```
string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        Console.WriteLine("Type in something you want to encrypt, using only lowercase letters.");
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        if(s == null) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            var a = s.Substring(i, 1);

            var x = abc.IndexOf(a, 0, abc.Length - 1, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            x = x + 3;

            if (x >= s.Length)
            {
                x = x - s.Length;
            }
            var b = s.Substring(x, 1);

            s = s.Replace(a, b);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I was trying to encrypt the user's input so that every letter was moved up three places in the alphabet. ex. abc = def, yes = bhv, etc. I tried your code and it returned the same thing. Also, I don't really understand the "StringComparison.Ordinal"

Comment: While finding index of 'a' in string of 'abc' variable it uses search algorithm. By saying compare with Ordinal means it will compare with raw byte representation of each character of 'abc'

Answer (score -1):

Your loop conditional is wrong. Either use <= or != .